# Check whether each row of a matrix is in another matrix [Python]

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have two matrices (or, better, 2D numpy arrays), `A` and `B`, with same number of columns (well, to be fair they have a different number of rows, however I'm just slicing both matrices on two columns) but different number of rows.

I would like to check whether every row in `A` is in `B` and what is the proper row index in `B`. I actually am using a regular loop, that is

```
for r in range(A.shape[0]):
    idx=numpy.where(numpy.all(B[:,[0,1]]==A[r,[1,2]],axis=1))
    idx=idx[0][0]
```

I was wondering if there are some smarter techniques to do so, possible using indexed methods and avoiding loops. I'm aware of numpy's `in1d`, but it does only work on 1D arrays.

For readers familiar with Matlab, I'm looking for the `ismember()` behaviour when the `'rows'` option is triggered.

Comment: What's the output format?

Comment: @Divakar the desired output, if possible, should be an array (or list) containing in *i*-th position the row index in `B` for the *i*-th row of `A`. E.g an output list of `[1,5,4]` means that the first row of `A` has been found in first row of `B`, the second row of `A` has been found in fifth row in `B` and the third row of `A` has been found in forth row in `B`. I am well aware that in Python indices start at 0, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a vectorized approach using [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html), like so -

```
np.argwhere((B[:,None,[0,1]] == A[:,[1,2]]).all(-1))
```

Alternatively, since you are dealing with rows of just `2` elements, a memory efficient approach that stays `2D` could be suggested, like so -

```
np.argwhere((B[:,None,0] == A[:,1]) & (B[:,None,1] == A[:,2]))
```

The output would be `(N,2)` shaped array, in which the first column gives us the row indices of `B` and the second column of `A` corresponding to matches across all elements in a row.

Sample run -

```
In [154]: A[:,[1,2]]
Out[154]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [0, 1]])

In [155]: B[:,[0,1]]
Out[155]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [0, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [1, 0]])

In [156]: np.argwhere((B[:,None,[0,1]] == A[:,[1,2]]).all(-1))
Out[156]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 4],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 1],
       [4, 2],
       [5, 2]])
```

Comment: Brilliant solution this one. I'll keep it in my bag. Too bad it's impractical for large matrices.

Comment: @Alessiox How large would be your large matrices?

Comment: At the moment I'm working on `A` circa 200 MB and `B` circa 10MB