# Index of matching rows in Pandas DataFrame [Python]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas DataFrames (`A` and `B`) with 2 columns and different number of rows.
They used to be numpy 2D matrices and they both contain integer values.
Is there any way to retrieve the indices of matching rows between those two?

I've been trying `isin()` or `query()` or `merge()`, without success.

This is actually a follow-up to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534466/check-whether-each-row-of-a-matrix-is-in-another-matrix-python): I'm trying with pandas dataframes since the original matrices are rather huge.

The desired output, if possible, should be an array (or list) containing in i-th position the row index in `B` for the i-th row of `A`. E.g an output list of `[1,5,4]` means that the first row of `A` has been found in first row of `B`, the second row of `A` has been found in fifth row in `B` and the third row of `A` has been found in forth row in `B`.

Comment: Can you provide an example with the desired output?

Comment: IIUC you could do `lhs.merge(rhs, how='outer', indicator=True)` this will add `_merge`  column which will indicate which rows are in `left_only`, `right_only` or `both`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would do it this way:

```
In [199]: df1.reset_index().merge(df2.reset_index(), on=['a','b'])
Out[199]:
   index_x  a  b  index_y
0        1  9  1       17
1        3  4  0        4
```

or like this:

```
In [211]: pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), on=['a','b'], suffixes=['_1','_2'])
Out[211]:
   index_1  a  b  index_2
0        1  9  1       17
1        3  4  0        4
```

data:

```
In [201]: df1
Out[201]:
   a  b
0  1  9
1  9  1
2  8  1
3  4  0
4  2  0
5  2  2
6  2  9
7  1  1
8  4  3
9  0  4

In [202]: df2
Out[202]:
    a  b
0   3  5
1   5  0
2   7  8
3   6  8
4   4  0
5   1  5
6   9  0
7   9  4
8   0  9
9   0  1
10  6  9
11  6  7
12  3  3
13  5  1
14  4  2
15  5  0
16  9  5
17  9  1
18  1  6
19  9  5
```

Comment: `inner` can be omit, becuse it is default parameter.

Comment: and maybe nicer is alternative `print (pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), on=['a','b']))

`

Comment: Thank you very much indeed guys. Just changing from `inner` to `right` matched also the expected output format. Not your fault, I edited my question later.

Answer (score -1):

Without merging, you can use `==` and then look if on each row there is `False`.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2,3,4],'b':[0,1,2,3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2,3,4],'b':[2,1,2,2,4]})
test = pd.DataFrame(index = df1.index,columns = ['test'])
for row in df1.index:
    if False in (df1 == df2).loc[row].values:
        test.ix[row,'test'] = False
    else:
        test.ix[row,'test'] = True

Out[1]:
    test
0   False
1   True
2   True
3   False
4   True
```