# Extract different rows from two numpy 2D arrays

Tags: numpy, row, extract

I generated a new random rows matrix B (50, 40) from a matrix A (100, 40):

```
B = A[np.random.randint(0,100,size=50)]  # it works fine.
```

Now, I want to take the rows from A that isn't in matrix B.

```
C = A not in B   # pseudocode.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
import numpy as np
A=np.random.randint(5,size=[100,40])
l=np.random.choice(100, size=50, replace=False)
B = A[l]
C= A[np.setdiff1d(np.arange(0,100),l)]
```

`l` stores the selected rows, and for `C` you take the complement of `l`. Then `C` is the required matrix.

Note that I set `l=np.random.choice(100, size=50, replace=False)` to avoid replacement. If you use `np.random.randint(0,100,size=50)` you may get repeated rows as the same number is selected at random.

Comment: Maybe you meant: A=np.random.randint(5,size=[100,40])
l=np.random.randint(0,100,size=50)
B = A[l]
C= A[np.setdiff1d(np.arange(0,100),l)] ?

Comment: If you take l=np.random.randint(0,100,size=50) you may have equal values in l. like l=[1,1,2,3,..]. Do you want to allow the possibility of taking the same row several times? If yes, you can indeed switch l to l=np.random.randint(0,100,size=50). If not, then the code in my answer guarantees that there is no repetition.

Answer (score 0):

Inspried by this question, [Check whether each row of a matrix is in another matrix [Python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534466/check-whether-each-row-of-a-matrix-is-in-another-matrix-python). First get indices of rows exists in B, then get difference from whole A indices. select rows using difference in the end.

```
index = np.argwhere((B[:,None,:] == A[:,:]).all(-1))[:, 1]
C = A[np.setdiff1d(np.arange(100), index)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (Disclaimer: i am its author) has efficient vectorized functionality for all these kinds of operations.

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
C = npi.difference(A, B)
```